# Can a noun be an individualizing modifier?

Tags: grammar, articles

There are some sliders on the web page. One of them is on the top. If I will put the "top" before the "slider", will the "top" become an individualizing modifier?

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to ***the*** top slider would obviously single out one specific slider (the one nearest the top of the display). But suppose your page had several slider controls on the top half of the display, and several different ones (doing completely different jobs) on the bottom half. Then you might refer to ***a*** top slider without it singling out any one specific control